# Ansible testing variable type

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm using an existing role, and I wish to modify it to extend its capabilities. Currently, one of its tasks is to create directories. These directories get passed as a variable containing a list of strings to the role, and then iterated over in a `with_items` statement. However, I would prefer to pass a list of dictionaries of the form e.g. `{name: foo, mode: 751}`.

So far so good; I can simply edit the role to make it take this sort of input. However, I also want to make it backwards compatible with the old format, i.e. where the items are strings.

Is there a way to test the type of a variable and then return different values (or perform different tasks) based on this? Perhaps using a Jinja2 filter? I was briefly looking at the [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) listed in the manual, but nothing caught my eye that could be used in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `default()` for backwards compatibility.

```
- file:
    path: "{{ item.name | default(item) }}"
    mode: "{{ item.mode | default(omit) }}"
    state: directory
  with_items: your_list
```

If the `item` has a `name` property, use it, else simply use the item itself.

Same goes for all other properties you might have in your dict. The special variable `omit` would omit the whole option from the task, as if no mode was passed to the `file` module. Of course you could set any other default.

Documentation references:

- [default](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables)
- [omit](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-undefined-variables-and-parameters)

Comment: Hmm, I was certain I had tried that.. Thanks, that's a nice and clean solution! Even though it's a bit more generic than my question would allow (since I was wrongfully looking for a type-checking solution), it fits the requirements precisely.

Comment: I know, it did actually not answer your question. Afaik there is no easy way to test for types. Jinja2 has a test filter `| string` but I never got it working. The `| iterable` filter works - unfortunately a string also is iterable... One could create custom filter plugins for that but I thought that would be bit of an overhead if one can simply work with `default`. At least in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, including a custom filter for what could be a simple one-line diff creates unwanted clutter.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution would be to have two tasks, and have they trigger with opposed conditions. Unfortunately, all items in the list will have to use the same form (you can't mix and match strings and dicts).

```
- name: create dirs (strings)
  file:
    ...
  with_items: items
  when: string(items[0])

- name: create dirs (dicts)
  file:
    ...
  with_items: items
  when: not string(items[0])
```

Comment: It's telling me `ERROR! 'string' is undefined`. Can you show me a link to the docs for that function?

Comment: @Joost I was using the jinja2 documentation, rather than the ansible documentation. In any case, udondan's answer is much better.